# How to convert an xml feed to html

Tags: xml, feed

I have a xml feed which needs to be converted to HTML. How can it be done? If somebody has any references on how to do it pls let me know. i need to show the feed in a wordpress site.

Thanks
Prady

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at XSL Transformations. There is a lot of good stuff online about this. Should do what you need it to do.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt

Just to add. I did a bit of looking on the wordpress plugins site and noticed plugins to allow use of XSLT with XML files. I hesitate to recommend one specifically as I have not used them, but this should hopefully get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should include some more context. If you just want to display [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) and `<iframe>` may be enough. If you want to use it as data, then you probably need some PHP library.